# facebook permernant access token user_posts?

Tags: facebook

I have no idea about how facebook tokens or APIs work, so please excuse my ignorance.

I am trying to get a access token to display my posts to my wall. My website is www.quadscene.co.nz and on the homepage I am trying to display all posts to wall.

I have created a access token using some tools within facebook, but they expire within about 2 hours, these token work fine when selecting the user_posts option or permission, however all other access tokens ive tried do not display posts.

I think its using OAuth.

Is there a way to create a token that will not expire? and has the user_posts permissions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens) to understand how OAuth works and what different access tokens are available.

Specifically, you need to look at the [long-lived tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#termtokens).